# Firebase -is it possible to block a phone number from signing up

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I authenticate users using phone auth. If I want to prevent a specific set of phone numbers from different users from signing up is this is possible. Eg they got banned, kicked off the platform, I kept a copy of their banned number in a ref. They try to sign up again with that same phone number. They can't proceed any further.

One way I thought of is once they enter their phone number, I can do a check against that ref before letting them proceed to sms. I was wondering is there a better way already built in. Maybe via the console?

phone number:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in

    // phone is verified, do a check on the kicked out ref before they can proceed to sms
}
```

sms:

```
let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID, verificationCode: smsCode)

Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (authDataResult, error) in

    // user is authenticated let them proceed inside the app or block them here
})
```

Comment: Don't you just want to disable the account in the Firebase Auth console, and leave it like that so they can't sign in?

Comment: What if they completely delete their account. That's an easy work around to signing up fresh again.

Comment: So you're saying that if you disable the account, the user can still delete it?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: hmmmmm, I never thought about that. That's a pretty good idea. I have to think that through.

Comment: That would work in anywhere except the EU because their laws say that  you have to remove all of a user's content if they request it. So I block disable their account, they put in a request for deletion, they can sign back up. Of course if they delete their account because of the laws I can't keep a copy of their phone number in the db either. I might be able to keep in the office but that doesn't prevent them from signing up again. Outside of the EU it's a good alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly try to block the number on the client app, but that's not really secure.  Client app code can be compromised and should not be trusted.  Your solution should be on a backend you control and can update without having to publish a new version of your app.

One thing you can do is write an [auth onCreate trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) with Cloud Functions that checks the phone number of the account that was just created, and uses the [Firebase Admin SDK to immediately delete the account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) if you don't want it to remain.

Comment: Cloud Functions is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to Identity Platform which supports [blocking functions](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/blocking-functions). You can use a `beforeCreate` event to block the sign up:

```
export.beforeCreate = authClient.functions().beforeCreateHandler((user, context) => {
  if (isDisallowed(user.phoneNumber)) {
    throw new gcipCloudFunctions.https.HttpsError(
     'invalid-argument', `"${user.phoneNumber}" is unauthorized.`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to use a backend for auth.

Of course, you can place the auth code in your app.

When a user attempt to sign up your platform, app may scan the blocked phone number list.

But it is not good for secure.

Can you make sure that your app will never de crack?

If it is possible, you can do it.

Thanks.